# How to classify the alternating group of degree n

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I need to classify the $$A_n$$ into several conjugacy classes.It's easy to find $S_n$'s conjugacy classes according to its type invariant. Since conjugacy classes of $S_n$ in $A_n$ may have elements which is not in $A_n$. It splits into two parts:one half in $A_n$,the other not. So here comes the question:when does the conjugacy class of $S_n$ is totally in $A_n$ and when it splits?

I might take $A_5$ for example.
In $S_5$,there are seven conjugacy class(take one of them to represent the class):{e},{(12)},{(12)(34)},{(123)},{(1234)},{123)(45)},{(12345)}.
In $A_5$,there are five:{e},{(12)(34)},{(123)},{(12345)},{(21345)}.
Then,why does the last two not in the same conjugacy?

Comment: Simple answer to your last question - they are only conjugate by an odd permutation, and there are no odd permutations in $A_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a precise *splitting criterion* for when a certain conjugacy class in $S_n$ that lies in $A_n$ splits into two conjugacy classes in $A_n$. In terms of writing permutations as cycles, the criterion goes as follows. Given an element $x \in A_n$, its conjugacy class in $A_n$ splits precisely when its cycle decomposition is made up out of cycles of distinct odd lengths. Caution, one has to be careful here with fixed points.